Discord bot returns error after sending embed
Ok so I have made a simple discord bot in python which after receiving command /student should send a embed message which it does. But after sending it still says sending command and after like 5 secconds it returns with error "The application did not respond". The code for the command looks like this:
@bot.tree.command(name="student", description="Přidá studenta do databáze")
async def student(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="REGISTRACE ŽÁKA", description="Zaregistrování žáka do databáze", color=0x009ade)
    embed.add_field(name="Jméno", value="napiš jméno žáka", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Střední ScioŠkola Brno")
    await interaction.channel.send(embed=embed)

I expected the command to send the embed message and than nothing. But it tried to do something but it couldn't do anything.

This is because you are not actually responding to the message.
All interaction.channel.send does is send a request for the bot to send a message in the channel.
To respond to application commands, use InteractionResponse which you can from the response attribute in Interaction.
@bot.tree.command()
async def mycommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="This is a command response")

Note that a command can only be responded to once, and must respond within 3 seconds of the command call.
